# Server re-install not working

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning, raid

my Ubuntu server recently crashed and since then I am struggling to get it back.

The server became unresponsive, ping returned sporadic returns and none of the services (SSH or Webmin) would connect. Shutdown wasn't possible either so I eventually had to switch it off.

The hard reset seems to have destroyed the root file system as the boot folder and many others were empty which meant I ended up in grub rescue mode after the reboot.

Well, decided to reinstall the OS which is where my journey begins.

First, what's working:

- New installation works without a problem
- All drives are found, including the raid
- when opening a shell in USB drive rescue mode I can mount all drives without a problem, (raid and backup drive)

Setup is

- SSD for the OS, home and swap (3 separate partitions)
- 3 4TB drives for a software raid 10 (one spare)
- a separate 2 TB swappable drive for offline backups

And here's where I am stuck:

- The server boots, shows the grub window and loads the kernel (lots of the usual status messages...)
- The last successful messages seem to be

  Begin: Loading essential drivers ... done

  Begin: Running scripts/init-premount ... done

  [19.000] random: fast init done

  Begin waiting for root file system

From there on there are lots of the below

```
Begin: Running scripts/local-block ... mdadm: no devices listed in config file were found
done
```

Until it finaly gives up with

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems...
...
ALERT! UUID=.... does not exist. Dropping to shell
```

After which the system freezes.

The UUID listed is correct and represents the boot partition of my SSD.

Thís somehow looks like none of the drives are accesible all of a sudden, neither the boot drive (UUID error) nor the raid array (mdadm error message)

I tried grup-updates and reinstalls which all give me strange errors. But whenever I a boot from my USB stick, select the rescue option and open a shell with the ssd-boot partition I can happily see and mount all partitions.

Some of the grup messages I am getting:

```
grub-update

Found linux image....

Found initrd image....

WARNING: Failed to connect lvmdat. Falling back to device scanning
grup-probe: error: cannot find a GRUB drive for dev/sdb1 check your device map
```

I checked /etc/fstab, and all entries look good to me. UUIDs macth what I would expect, / SWAP and are available

Anyone's got an idea of where to look next? My next step would be to completely repartition the SSD which I would like to avoid...

Thanks
Thomas

Comment: This sounds like a disk failure to me. I'd try [checking the SMART status](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1) on all your disks.

Comment: Hm, just a bad boot sector on the SSD? I ran a file system check on all SSD partions and it didn't show any errors. Would also not explain why seemingly all 3 (physical) drives produce problems. In a Windows world I'd say I need a driver for the HDD controller,  but here?

Comment: Your question doesn't specify booting in BIOS mode, and the problem might not be in the boot sector even if you are booting in that way. A filesystem check might or might not reveal a problem. As I said, I recommend you check the SMART data.

Comment: Thanks Rod, I did check the SMART data on all 5 drives on the server and they all show "Health".

Comment: Went ahead and started to delete the partitions on the ssd. First one to go was the root partition. Did a fresh server install and hey, back to normal!? The whole boot sequence looks different (normal) now, whereas before it came up with a much larger font and different messages. No idea what has been lurking on this partition but glad that I got my server back. Thanks a lot for helping me along!